# Chrome theme discontinued - copying theme from one machine to another

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

my favourite Google Chrome theme, The Google Science Fair 2013 has been discontinued from the chrome web store. As I still have it installed on some machines, is there a way of copying that theme file and manually installing it on my new PC?